# Angular 5 star rating bar

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to show 5 star rating bar using angular and currently my code work only for integers with full star. But i want to use half stars for decimal values. how can i change this code. I can't use IF in my angular version.

```
<li ng-repeat="Star in [1,2,3,4,5]">
     <div ng-switch="Item.ItemDetails.Rating >= Star">
          <div ng-switch-when="true">
               <img src="~/Images/star.png" class="star" />
           </div>
           <div ng-switch-when="false">
               <img src="~/Images/star_gray.png" class="star" />
           </div>
     </div>
</li>
```

Comment: if you want to help us, please provide Plunker or Fiddle

Comment: you can create this by easily using directive concept in angular http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/03/rating-stars-in-angular-js-using.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this symple solution..

```
<li ng-repeat="Star in [1,2,3,4,5]">
                                    <div ng-switch="store.Rating >= Star">
                                        <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                            <img src="~/Images/star.png" class="star" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-switch-when="false">
                                            <div ng-switch="store.Rating > (Star-1)">
                                                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                                    <img src="~/Images/star_half.png" class="star" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div ng-switch-when="false">
                                                    <img src="~/Images/star_gray.png" class="star" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this example by using bootstrap might be helpful:  <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFKejRU0G2wmkD7GlNdH?p=preview)</kbd>

[image]

**HTML**

```
<form class="Scroller-Container" ng-submit="submit()" ></form>

    <rating  
           value="rate" 
           max="max" 
           readonly="isReadonly" 
           on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" 
           on-leave="hoveringLeave(rate)" >
   </rating>
    <span 
         class="badge" 
         ng-class="{'badge-warning': percent<30, 'badge-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'badge-success': percent>=70}" 
         ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">
         {{percent}}%
    </span>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var RatingDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {

    $scope.myRate = 0;

     $scope.submit = function() {
         console.log($scope.percent) ; //null
     }

     $scope.rate = 1;
     $scope.max = 5;
     $scope.isReadonly = false;
     $scope.percent = 20;

      $scope.hoveringOver = function(value,object) {
        console.log('hoveringOver', value);
        $scope.overStar = value;
        $scope.percent = (100 * $scope.overStar) / $scope.max;
      };

       $scope.hoveringLeave = function(rate) {
         console.log('hoveringLeave',  $scope.rate);

       $scope.percent = (100 * $scope.rate) / $scope.max;
      };
    };
```

You can override it and provide custom image. But the way is the same (with `ng-class` for example)

BTW, here is a icon library from there you can fetch star/half-star/empty star: [Awesome Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

Answer (score 2):

despite your question is qualified as just an AngularJs question I have a other suggestion to approach your desired effect with algo Angular Js but a little bit of Css trick.

First I would get two **5 star** images one 'Empty' or gray and one 'Full' or yellow like so:
[image: Empty stars]

Then I would create a **div** with the **gray** stars and a **overlay div** with the **bright yellow** ones. Both using `background-image` instead of regular `<img>` tags, doing this I would be able to change the width of the overlay div to achieve the amount of rating necessary.

**Check out this [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xes4v/1/)** (I apologize for the poor images, it was what I could get from google images for a quick demo - play around with the width in the full-star div to see)

First I would organize the Html as the following:

```
<div class="star-rating">
    <!-- The '|| 0' would prevent an undefined or null value on the Rating property -->
    <div class="full-star" style="width: {{Item.ItemDetails.Rating * 20 || 0}}%"></div>         
    <div class="empty-star"> </div>
</div>
```

The width on the full-star will determine how much of the star would appear.

With the following **Css**:

```
/* This is just an example instead of using <img> tags you can use background-image and achive half-star results */
.star-rating {
    position: relative;
    /*  other styles to match preference */
}

.full-star {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('PATH_TO ~/Images/star.png');
    /*  other styles to match preference */        
}

.empty-star {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
    background-image: url('PATH_TO ~/Images/star_gray.png');
    /*  other styles to match preference */
}
```

Cheers.